# Как задать выполнение кода телеграм боту

Tags: python, selenium, telegram, бот, telebot

У меня есть код который я хочу выполнить в телеграм боте. Возможно ли это сделать с помощью pyTelegramBotAPI?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import telebot
import config

driver = webdriver.Chrome()



driver.get(input("link here"))
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="joinform-gamecode"]')
search_box.send_keys(input('Code here '))

search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="joinform-name"]')
search_box.send_keys(' ᠌ ᠌ ᠌᠌ ᠌ ᠌ ᠌ ᠌ ᠌ ')

search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="participate-form-code"]/button')
search_button.click()
time.sleep(10)

search_but = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div')
search_but.click()

search_bu = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="w0"]/div/div/div[3]/div/a[3]/i')
search_bu.click()

print(driver.current_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю так:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import telebot
import config

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

token='token'
bot=telebot.Telebot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['run_selenium'])
def run_selenium_command(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Starting...")
    driver.get(input("link here>> "))
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    
    search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="joinform-gamecode"]')
    search_box.send_keys(input('Code here>> '))
    
    search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="joinform-name"]')
    search_box.send_keys(' ᠌ ᠌ ᠌᠌ ᠌ ᠌ ᠌ ᠌ ᠌ ')
    
    search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="participate-form-code"]/button')
    search_button.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    
    search_but = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div')
    search_but.click()
    
    search_bu = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="w0"]/div/div/div[3]/div/a[3]/i')
    search_bu.click()
    
    print(driver.current_url)

bot.infinity_poling()
```

Либо оберните свой код в функцию:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import telebot
import config

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


def some_function_with_selenium():
    driver.get(input("link here>> "))
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    ...
    search_bu.click()
    print(driver.current_url)


token='token'
bot=telebot.Telebot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['run_selenium'])
def run_selenium_command(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Starting...")
    some_function_with_selenium()
```

Я думаю суть ясна.

Comment: Честно говоря не понял как это должно работать. Я скопировал код, подставил значение токена, запустил но ничего не происходит. Когда обернул в функцию перестало запрашивать ссылку в редакторе.

Comment: Странно, возможно я Вас неправильно понял, попробуйте сформулировать вопрос точнее.

Comment: Я хочу чтобы телеграм бот запрашивал ссылку от пользователя, затем переходил по ней и делал действия из кода, а затем возвращал конечную ссылку пользователю. Я новичок в программировании поэтому прошу прощения за не правильную формулировку.

Comment: @FrendyyS
`bot.send_message(user_id, text)`

Comment: А как это использовать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @FrendyyS
Где вам нужно, там и используйте (вместо print).
user_id можно получить так: `message.from_user.id`